# How to customize the control when setBackCommand is called?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using back command to go back to the previous form. But I would like to enable Buttons/Labels when this back command is called. I would like to show difference in the form control coming to the first form directly and going from second form to the first form.

Code:

First Form:

```
Button: finishActivity 
Label: clock 
CheckBox: pickEndTime.setVisible(false);
Date Picker: startTimeDatePick.setVisible(false);
```

Second Form:

```
getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> prev.showBack());
```

When this occurs I would like to enable the buttons mentioned in the first form.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> prev.showBack());
```

Do:

```
getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> prev.mySpecialShow());
```

Then in the form implement `mySpecialShow()` to do:

```
pickEndTime.setVisible(false); 
startTimeDatePick.setVisible(false);
showBack();
```

etc.

Comment: Shai, prev.mySpecialShow() cannot be valid until the method is static. My method cannot be static. How can I call method of another form from this form. I'm little confused with the use of the method. can you please share any working example link. Sorry if my question is simple.

Comment: `if(prevForm instanceof MyForm)) ((MyForm)prevForm).mySpecialShow(); else prevForm.show();`